# SuperOneClick freezes at "Running psneuter" while rooting. What can I do?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I tried to root my new Samsung Galaxy S II today using the instructions in the [CF-Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1103399) thread and in the videos provided by [this guy](http://www.youtube.com/user/mattj101101) on YouTube.

I was nearly across the finish line, but when I click the big "Root" button on SuperOneClick, it freezes at "Running psneuter" and won't go any further or shut down (without Task Manager intervention).

I've tried leaving it for > 10 mins, turning off all antivirus and I've tried 2 different SuperOneClick versions (1.9.1 and 1.7) to no avail.

Because of this, I'm pretty sure my root isn't going through properly. Mainly because when I [check if my phone is rooted properly](http://matrixrewriter.com/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=Root%20&%20rooting%20your%20phones) I can't get `su` access in shell.

Any ideas/thoughts about what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an answer I got a thread I made at [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1114938), it looks like the phone actually is rooted because the whole idea with the CF-Root Kernel I used is that it comes pre rooted (which makes me feel slightly sheepish!).

Comment: Looks like someone patched the security vulnerability psneuter uses. :)

Answer (score 0):

disable antivirus in your system before extracting superoneclick and while running it

Comment: The OP specifically said he's already tried turning off his anti-virus software. Besides, this question already has an accepted answer: the phone was already rooted.